# Internal API constructor DefaultDomainObjectSet(Class<T>) has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Is there a way to turn off this warning? When I used **--warning-mode all stacktrace** I saw that problem comes from internal API. This error is so annoying, so I would like to fix it or turn the warning off.

Comment: I think it is caused by one of these plugins. I have it too:

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

And i also think they will update these plugins as well. So that the deprecation would not be a problem.

Comment: @NumanKaraaslan, FYI, My stack trace points to the line with `apply plugin: "com.android.application"` statement.

Answer (score -3):

I am an amateur and spare me if it sounds ridiculous but downgrading my gradle worked, previously 6.4 was being used now I am using 5.6.4